# Why do multiple iframes in all major browsers navigate as a single frame, rather than separately?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I have 2 iframes in my HTML document. I've given the user "Back" and "Forward" buttons on each iframe. However, when I use these buttons, the back and forward navigation on the particular frame doesn't work properly; it interleaves with the navigation history of the other.

For example, consider the following sequence of events:

Event 1: Click link in Frame 2
Event 2: Click link in Frame 1

Now, when I click the following order of navigation, these things happen:

Click "back" on frame 2: Frame 1 goes back!
Click "forward" on frame 2: Frame 1 goes forward! (this is not because Frame 1 doesn't have anything to forward to; I have tested that possibility as well with same result)

Note that the back and forward URLs are not mixed; windows still maintain their separate locations. Just the order of navigation is interleaved.

Why does this happen? This is consistent across all browsers, so I'm guessing this is not a "bug" and there is at least some explanation for this bizarre behavior?

Note: I am using the following JS code to achieve this functionality:

```
window.frames['iframe_' + x].history.back();  
//x is a suffix that is different for both iframes
```

Comment: "I've given the user "Back" and "Forward" buttons on each iframe" — How?

Comment: Using the simple Javascript I posted at the bottom. For forward, I use the forward() function instead of back(). Both are standard; It works well except for the issue noted here.